# React native iOS performance stats

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, expo

I recently started my main app for iOS with React Native. I turned on the performance monitor on Expo but I do not know what is a good stat for the app. I have uploaded the picture of the monitor and was wondering are these stats good or should I work more on optimizing my app?

Thank you for any help. and please feel free to suggest any other tools, techniques or anything else.[image: Performance monitor stats]

Answer (score 0):

you can use react devtools to profile problematic parts of your app and determine what the bottlenecks are. https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/09/10/introducing-the-react-profiler.html

more info about using react devtools with react-native in the readme: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-devtools#usage-with-react-native